# Livebinding interfaces in delphi

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, livebindings

I created a small project using Delphi FireMonkey platform to try out the new live bindings feature. I want to populate TListBox with items `TList<IFoo>` and I use [BOCollection example](https://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/radstudiodemos/branches/RadStudio_XE2/LiveBindings/BOCollection). `BindList.FormatExpressions[0]` has values similar to the ones in the example.

```
ControlExpression = 'Text'
SourceExpression = 'Current.Name'
```

Now, if I call `BindList.FillList` then I get the exception "Couldn't find Name". However, if I use list of objects (`TList<TFoo>` instead of `TList<IFoo>`) then there's no exception raised and list is populated correctly - it works! So it seems that livebinding can't find properties of interfaces.

Definition of IFoo is the following:

```
IFoo = interface
  function GetName: string;
  procedure SetName(const AValue: string);
  property Name: string read GetName write SetName;
end;
```

Is it possible to make livebinding work with interfaces?

Comment: Try inheriting the interface from IInvokable or add $M+ compiler switch to add the RTTI. Anyway I think LiveBindings cannot work with interfaces but I am not sure.

Comment: @StefanGlienke Unfortunately that did not work. I wonder if there's any particular reason, why Embarcadero didn't make it work with interfaces.